# Replace strings in large file

Tags: c++, io

I have a server-client application where clients are able to edit data in a file stored on the server side. The problem is that the file is too large in order to load it into the memory (8gb+). There could be around 50 string replacements per second invoked by the connected clients. So copying the whole file and replacing the specified string with the new one is out of question.

I was thinking about saving all changes in a cache on the server side and perform all the replacements after reaching a certain amount of data. After reaching that amount of data I would perform the update by copying the file in small chunks and replace the specified parts.

This is the only idea I came up with but I was wondering if there might be another way or what problems I could encounter with this method.

Comment: Sounds like some form of database rather than a flat file would help (a lot).

Comment: In fact, make it a nosql brand or so for great glory

Comment: It sounds like a database I have to admit but not it's not :). Unfortunately the file content is no fit for a database. It's an editor for a 3Dterrain where many people can edit it.

Comment: Since you talk about "strings", I guess that's what the file contains inside. When the user asks for the data, don't give him the whole file, instead split it into chunks (say, 100 lines per chunk), and give the user only those chunks that they need. After editing you will be able to merge the chunks back

Comment: A quick search leads me to believe that the global road network is  ~1 TB, and most of it is in databases. Sure, as Apple has shown, that's not trivial to work with, but certainly possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have more than 8GB of data which is edited by many users simultaneously, you are far beyond what can be handled with a flatfile.

You seriously need to move this data to a database. Regarding your comment that "the file content is no fit for a database": sorry, but I don't believe you. Especially regarding your remark that "many people can edit it" - that's one more reason to use a database. On a filesystem, only one user at a time can have write access to a file. But a database allows concurrent write access for multiple users.

We could help you to come up with a database schema, when you open a new question telling us how your data is structured exactly and what your use-cases are.

Comment: Right now my terrain is split in different parts (pure terrain, buildings, environment). So I guess splitting the terrain in chunks and saving these chunks in the database would be the right way to go? (Same for building-chunks and environment-chunks)

Comment: short answer: it depends. The long answer would warrant a new question.

Answer (score 1):

You could use some form of indexing on your data (in a separate file) to allow quick access to the relevant parts of this gigantic file (we've been doing this with large files successfully (~200-400gb), but as Phillipp mentioned you should move that data to a database, especially for the read/write access. Some frameworks (like [OSG](http://www.openscenegraph.org/projects/osg)) already come with a database back-end for 3d terrain data, so you can peek there, how they do it.